# Private Information Retrieval——which framework is using effectively now？

Tags: pir

I have read some PIR papers, but I find the related discuss of PIR framework was in 7 years ago.

So could somebody tell me，what is the mainstream PIR method in industry now？

Comment: [This comparison](https://research.google/pubs/pub51028/) may be relevant, although I haven't really heard of PIR discussed in terms of "frameworks" as much as in terms of "protocols", so I don't know engineering effort has been expended to apply things to industry yet (although I know that industry is interested --- Google is hiring researchers in PIR iirc).

Comment: Thanks for your help.I find some open-source framework to integrate in my project，so I wander whether this area has some mature solutions.

Comment: By the way, do you hear of the github's project which named 'XPIR'? Thanks for your patient answer.